# O que é lógica de programação e pensamento computacional?

Tags: ciência-da-computação

Ultimamente eu andei vendo alguns cursos de programação e notei que eles falam de muitas coisas como frameworks e ferramentas e focam pouco na linguagem em si, e isso me levou a questionar algo a respeito da lógica de programação, e uma dúvida básica que me surgiu nesse caminho foi a respeito do pensamento computacional.

Não encontrei nenhum curso que aborde isso de uma forma que não seja superficial, muito menos livros (não achei nenhum mais creio que deve ter) sobre pensamento computacional e lógica.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria que essas dúvidas fosse sanadas.

## Dúvidas

1. O que seria esta tal de lógica de programação e o pensamento computacional?
2. Qual a relação que um tem com outro?

Comment: Espero que venha boas respostas e não achismos (que serão devidamente negativados). O tema é bom demais pra ser desperdiçado.

Comment: Essa pergunta é ótima. Porém, abre espaço para respostas do tipo 'achismo' (o que não acho errado, já que a pergunta dá brechas para respostas subjetivas). Não deveríamos incentivar e influenciar, respostas boas, na base da ameaça. A negativação acontecerá naturalmente por parte de quem não gostar da resposta ou da pergunta. É apenas minha humilde opinião.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. qualquer pergunta você pode responder orientado a achismo ;)

Comment: @gato, sim. Só que pra alguns isso é sinônimo de negativação.

Comment: ... Porém nem todas as perguntas abrem espaço para respostas baseadas no achismo. Por exemplo: Quanto é 1 + 1 ? Pra essa pergunta só existe uma resposta. O cara pode até responder que não seja 2. Ele tentaria argumentar muito. Mas no fim a grande maioria das pessoas sabem a resposta certa.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. tem pergunta que é só achismo, aí a gente fecha. Tem pergunta que é "exata". E tem as que são "boas subjetivas", que [são tratadas nesse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/70). Nesses casos basta negativar o que vier com problema. Sobre negativação, não é ameaça, é parte do modelo do site. Eu como usuário (mod nao tem privilégio em voto) desço o negativo em porcaria se a pessoa não arruma, que é para ajudar as pessoas que vem aqui aprender. Quem se ofende com negativo não entendeu o modelo do site (nem deveria participar de coisa séria para começo de conversa).

Comment: Mas uma coisa é básica e pelo tempo que eu tenho de site posso falar com tranquilidade. O pessoal que realmente faz a parte boa do site não tem problema nenhum com o modelo de negativar coisa errada e positivar (e até premiar) coisa boa.. Geralmente quem cria muito caso aqui e no meta tem "ficha suja", é usuário que não pensa no coletivo (eu diria uns 80% dos casos). Mas não vou me estender mais aqui nos comments pois estou começando a fugir muito do tópico, ja tratei dos negativos e do pessoal problemático [aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2096/70) e em outros posts.

Comment: Beleza, Bacco. Entendi. Então pode existir respostas e perguntas subjetivas (que não deixa de ser um achismo), contanto que sejam boas. Ótimo. Entendo o seu critério de fechar perguntas, mas não esqueça de pelo menos olhar novamente pra ver se o usuário editou. Fora isso, tenho nada a reclamar, minha opinião já foi dada e nenhuma verdade é absoluta.

Comment: ... Como você, eu também desço o dedo no negativo quando vejo resposta ou perguntas com conteúdo arrogante e prepotente, que fogem do contexto. Pra mim, arrogância e prepotência também são critérios.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship.seu voto, suas regras. (desde que não viole as regras do site, claro - aí valem as do site, que não é um "serviço público", ou seja quem não estiver contente com as regras pode achar outro lugar ou fazer um site "melhor" kk :)

Comment: Olha a ironia, Baccão. kkkkkkkkkkkk.

Answer (score 15):

Olha, essa pergunta é bem profunda e a resposta pode ser exaustiva, vamos tentar resumir de uma forma até complementar:

Você conhece ou já ouviu falar do Assembly?

Vou colocar um trechinho de código aqui, pode ser divertido:

```
MOV AH,01h      ;Função 1 do DOS (leitura de caractere)
INT 21h         ;lê 1o caracter, retorna código ASCII ao registrador AL
MOV BL,AL       ;move o código ASCII para o registrador BL por enquanto
INT 21h         ;lê 2o caracter, retorna código ASCII ao registrador AL
                ;--- Impressão dos 2 caracteres, na ordem invertida ---
MOV AH,02h      ;Função 2 do DOS (escrita de caractere)
MOV DL,AL       ;move o código ASCII do 2o caractere lido p/ DL
INT 21h         ;imprime o caractere cujo codigo está em DL
MOV DL,BL       ;move o código ASCII do 1o caracter lido p/ DL
MOV AH,2h       ;função 2h, imprime caracter
INT 21h         ;imprime o caractere cujo codigo está em DL
```

Este trecho (que pode ser encontrado na apostila da UFES) mostra como escrever um código que entra com dois caracteres e imprime os mesmo em ordem inversa.

O que acontece aqui é basicamente uma assimilação ao cérebro humano, de como as coisas são alocadas, no computador é necessário indicar de forma direta (apontar exatamente onde a informação será alocada na memória), o pensamento computacional é este e, se você parar pra pensar, é algo muito limitado e que dá a impressão de que a máquina é uma coisa extremamente burra... E é exatamente isso, ela é!

Aí é que entra a lógica de programação.

Na lógica de programação, quando vamos para linguagens de mais alto nível, nos são oferecido condições que abstraem esses inúmeros e complexos casos da linguagem de máquina, que por mais complexo que parece, é algo muito simples se comparada à linguagem que máquina, que se resume à estados elétricos (ligado e desligados, representados por 1 e 0, linguagem binária, que você com certeza sabe o que é). Essas condições das linguagens de alto nível, como C, C++ ou C# (que parecem coisas de baixo nível se comprados a Python, PHP...) são, por exemplo, os if's, os else's, as variáveis e diversas outras funções que as linguagens oferecem.
Essas funcionalidades mais simples de serem lidas facilitam a relação homem-máquina, que nos possibilitam criar funções mais complexas e que tornam o computador mais poderoso.

Uma comparação simples dessas formas de pensamento é por exemplo o ENIAC, que foi programado puramente com linguagem binária, não tinha nem sequer o potencial de uma calculadora moderna, o pensamento das máquinas hoje é de um potencial completamente diferente e seu poder de pensamento (possibilitado pelas novas técnicas computacionais que surgem) tem uma evolução que, segundo a ciência da computação, dobra o seu poder a cada dois anos, o que é assustador de certa forma.

Espero que tenha solucionado suas dúvidas, se houver alguma coisa que não tenha te elucidado é só perguntar. Até mais.

Answer (score 10):

Pensamento computacional é uma estratégia para modelar soluções e resolver problemas de forma eficiente

O pensamento computacional pode ser organizado em quatro etapas:

1. Decomposição: dividir a questão em problemas menores e, portanto, mais fáceis.
2. Padrões: identificar o padrão ou os padrões que geram o problema.
3. Abstração: ignorar os detalhes de uma solução de modo que ela possa ser válida para diversos problemas.
4. Algoritmo: estipular ordem ou sequência de passos para resolver o problema

Basicamente, a ideia é reformular problemas que aparentam ser de difícil resolução e transformá-los em algo capaz de ser compreendido, focando, para isso, em cada uma de suas fases, a fim de lidar com as incertezas que muitas vezes os cercam

Lógica de Programação é a técnica de desenvolver sequências lógicas para atingir um determinado objetivo, uma sequência de passos para atingir um determinado objetivo. A lógica de programação trata basicamente de construir algoritmos que serão transformados em programas de computador.

Answer (score 7):

1. Imagine o computador como a pessoa mais metodica do mundo. A Lógica de programação é a forma como você fala pra essa pessoa fazer as atividades que você quer. O Pensamento computacional é a forma que você pensa para resolver um determinado problema. Ambos são interessantes para o desenvolvimento da lógica até mesmo na aprendizagem.
2. Os dois se relacionam na forma como Homem e Máquina se unem para criar um "roteiro" que consiga solucionar um problema.

Answer (score 7):

O termo *Pensamento Computacional* é o processo de entender como resolver um **problema**.

A **resolução** deste problema pode ser por computador ou ser humano, sendo esta [uma etapa **opcional**](https://www.edsurge.com/news/2018-02-25-the-5th-c-of-21st-century-skills-try-computational-thinking-not-coding) dentro do Pensamento Computacional, uma vez que este pode ter um fim em si mesmo.

E como o computador pode resolver? Com alguma lógica de programação.

## Explicação

O processo de pensamento computacional envolve inicialmente o problema a ser resolvido e o entendimento das maneiras que ele pode ser resolvido.

Existem 2 maneiras de caracterizar este processo. Primeiro, usando os "[Quatro Cs](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zp92mp3/revision/1)"

1. **decomposição**: dividir um problema ou sistema complexo em pedaços menores, mais manuseáveis.
2. **reconhecimento de padrão**: procurar por semelhanças entre e dentro dos problemas
3. **abstração**: foco apenas nas informações importantes, ignorando detalhes irrelevantes
4. **algoritmos**: desenvolver uma solução passo-a-passo para o problema, ou as regras para seguir para resolvê-lo

Ou o "[Três As](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_thinking)":

1. **Abstração**: formulação do problema
2. **Automação**: expressão da solução
3. **Análise**: execução da solução e avaliação

Note que ambos são bem semelhantes.

Nas 2 caracterizações acima, a etapa que envolve a lógica de programação é sempre a última, que envolve o desenvolvimento final da solução planejada e sua execução.  Mas, como disse logo no começo, a etapa de execução é opcional.

Mesmo sendo opcional, a lógica de programação é um meio popular e eficaz de ensinar o Pensamento Computacional.

## Exemplo prático

Se você, por exemplo, você está na sua casa e deseja encontrar um amigo. Você sabe que ele está no Shopping. Como chegar até ele? Este é o seu problema.

Para isto, você precisa considerar o transporte a ser usado, as rotas disponíveis, o melhor trajeto (mais seguro, econômico, rápido, conhecido, etc). Após considerar tudo isto, você desenha a rota ideal e a segue, passo-a-passo.

Neste exemplo acima, o planejamento é o pensamento computacional e seguir as direções é expressada pela lógica de programação.

Answer (score 5):

Um computador é capaz de fazer apenas um punhado de operações básicas. A máquina de Turing foi o primeiro modelo de máquina computacional, e ainda não existe um computador inerentemente mais capaz que a máquina de Turing.

É mais fácil, hoje em dia, modelar um computador elementar como um processador RISC bem básico. Há modelos acadêmicos com apenas uma instrução, mas um modelo com meia dúzia de instruções já é bem mais fácil de entender.

Lógica de programação é o método formal de representar um programa. Pode-se usar um formalismo de nível mais alto, que então vai ser compilado/interpretado/traduzido para um formalismo de nível mais baixo.

Pensamento computacional é "colocar-se no lugar do computador", analisar um problema e quebrá-lo em pequenos pedaços elementares, que possam ser expressos em lógica de programação, e finalmente possam ser processados por um computador.

Para fazer isso, vale usar as técnicas especificadas nas outras respostas, e também vale a criatividade e "instinto" do programador.