# Logica de Programação e Pensamento computacional são a mesma coisa?

Tags: terminologia, lógica, princípios-de-programação

Logica de Programação e Pensamento computacional são a mesma coisa? Eu estive estudando este dois temas, para mim parecia assuntos distintos mas agora vejo que são a mesma coisa, uma está ligada a outra, estou certo?

Comment: "Lógica de programação" não é um conceito formal, até onde eu sei. "Lógica" é (lembro de uma resposta sobre isso aqui no site mas não consegui achar). "Pensamento computacional" talvez seja nas áreas de psicologia, pedagogia e ciência cognitiva. Todo conceito depende do contexto ou marco teórico em que ele é definido, e esses são conceitos são muito usados de maneira frouxa, sem contexto nenhum. Então basicamente podem ser usados pra dizer a mesma coisa ou não. Sim, com certeza dá pra achar pontos em comum, mas se parar pra pensar também dá pra achar diferenças.

Comment: Como exemplo de como esses termos são usados de maneira frouxa, veja as definições da resposta abaixo. Não precisa nem entrar no mérito do que está sendo dito, repare só na escolha de palavras. Lógica "é" uma "habilidade"? Pensamento "é" "ter uma forma de pensar"?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que é lógica de programação e pensamento computacional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434717/o-que-%c3%a9-l%c3%b3gica-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-pensamento-computacional)

Answer (score -3):

Eu busquei estas frases e encontrei as seguintes definações.

> A lógica de programação é a habilidade essencial de desenvolver
> algoritmos eficazes e estruturar soluções lógicas para problemas
> complexos. Ela é a base fundamental para a criação de software e a
> instrução de computadores para executar tarefas específicas.
>
> Em termos simples, a lógica de programação é a capacidade de organizar
> e transmitir instruções de maneira coerente e sequencial, de modo que
> um computador possa executar as ações desejadas.

https://codecrush.com.br/blog/logica-de-programacao

> Pensamento computacional significa ter uma forma de pensar ou até
> mesmo ter uma estratégia para resolver determinadas situações ou
> problemas de forma eficaz com bases computacionais. Muitas vezes, por
> envolver a palavra “Computacional”, imagina-se que ela está
> relacionada apenas à computação, mas não, qualquer problema pode ser
> resolvido com o pensamento computacional.

https://blog.betrybe.com/tecnologia/pensamento-computacional-tudo-sobre/

Parece que estas definações estão descrevendo a mesma coisa. Se você pode dividir uma tarefa de modo a fazer tarefas mais simples e depois juntar os resultados dessas tarefas menores, você pode usar o mesmo processo para tranformar a tarefa para criar instruições para o computador, ou seja, um algoritmo.

A segunda citação explica que este modo de pensar não aplica somente aos computadores. Tambem pode usar estas técnicas para abordar um problema sem um computador, como montar um quebra-cabeça.